# How to select Date from database?

Tags: ms-access

User will enter a date, for example "7/1/2015". Then I will check in database and return some result if match. Note in database there is Date/Time but user will enter only date.

Below I have a following database set up in Access and col "StartBy" type is Date/Time

```
Table = "workStartTable"
|----|------------------------|
| ID | StartBy                |
|----|------------------------|
| 1  | 7/1/2015 2:30:00 PM    |
| 2  | 1/22/2013 8:00:00 AM   |
| 3  | 10/22/2014 10:25:00 AM |
| 4  | 4/5/2010 5:00:00 PM    |
| 5  | 7/3/2015               |
|----|------------------------|
```

I have created the following query which kind of work. This below query will work because there is not time for this record in database (7/3/2015), but "07/01/2015" will not work because "07/01/2015" has the time.

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM workStartTable WHERE StartBy = #" & "07/03/2015" & "#;"
```

Please note I already have tried the following below queries and they don't return any result:

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM workStartTable WHERE StartBy = " & "07/03/2015" & ";"
Dim query As String = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM workStartTable WHERE StartBy LIKE % " & "07/03/2015" & " %;"
Dim query As String = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM workStartTable WHERE StartBy LIKE " & "07/03/2015" & " %;"
```

Comment: What is your DBMS and what is the exact type of the StartBy column ?

Comment: it is a Acccess database and Col "StartBy" is type Date/Time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [DateValue](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/DateValue-Function-03878f08-b0db-42df-8a0c-279939637c6f) function: `DateValue(StartBy)`

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM workStartTable WHERE DateValue(StartBy) = #2015-07-03#;
```

A potentially better performing option, as pointed out by Gord Thompson in a comment, would be to use:

```
WHERE StartBy >= #2015-07-03# AND StartBy < #2015-07-04#
```

which would make the time part irrelevant.

Comment: Not [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), but workable if performance is not terribly important. The sargable equivalent would be `WHERE StartBy >= #2015-07-03# AND StartBy < #2015-07-04#`.